# Compute Becker's (1988) standardized mean change based only on difference score and t-statistic (meta-analysis)

Tags: repeated-measures, meta-analysis, effect-size

In my meta-analysis, I'm combining independent-sample designs with single-group pretest-posttest designs. To ensure interpretability across designs, I would like to quantify the effects from pretest-posttest designs as standardized mean changes using raw score standardization.

When pre and post means and *SD*s are available, the effect size can be easily computed via `metafor::escalc(measure = "SMCR")`. However, at least one relevant paper in my database reports only the change from pretest to posttest, $\Delta$ = 0.15, as well as the results of the paired-samples *t*-test, *t*(49) = 2.84, *p* = .007.

The `metafor` documentation explains how to compute SMRCs on the basis of change scores, but to do so one would still need the *SD* of the pretest. While one can easily back-calculate the *SD* of the change score based on the *t*-statistic, I'm not aware the same can be done for the pretest *SD*. Of course I could also compute the repeated-measures effect size *d*<sub>rm</sub> (Morris & DeShon, 2002, Eq. 28), and then transform it to a raw-score standardized *d* (Morris & DeShon, 2002, Eq. 11).

$d_{rm} = \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{2.84}{\sqrt{50}} = 0.402$

$d = d_{rm}\sqrt{2(1-\rho)} = 0.402\sqrt{2(1-0.7)} = 0.311$

However, this computation differs from that in `metafor::escalc(measure = "SMCR")`, which I understand follows the approach proposed by Becker (1988). As Morris and DeShon (2002) point out, "the two approaches will not produce exactly the same value" (p. 111), especially when variances are not equal.

My question is thus whether I can compute the SMCR, as per Becker (1988), on the basis of just the change score and the *t* statistic -- either in `metafor` or by hand. Thanks for any pointers!

**References**:

- Becker, B. J. (1988). Synthesizing standardized mean-change measures. *British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 41*, 257–278.
- Morris, S. B., & DeShon, R. P. (2002). Combining effect size estimates in meta-analysis with repeated measures and independent-groups designs. *Psychological Methods, 7*, 105-125.